# How to create a notification in Azure DevOps, that sends a email to initiator / creator when an PR is created

Tags: azure-devops, notifications

In the following document, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/exclude-self-from-email?view=azure-devops, MS specified a way to exclude initiator when sending out a notification. But how to acheive the opposite?

My point is, in order to remember all the PR I've created through out different organization, I would like to be notified by email for every pull request I've created. Is there a way to create a notification without specifying my actual name, but using something like "@Me", or "initiator"? So that this notification can be set as a project / team level, and being applied to each team member if they want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, friend of mine told me, that using `[Me]` keyword in the `Value` field of the "notification - filter criteria" editor will do the trick.